# Adding a line below menu items on hover?

Tags: html, css, transition, menuitem

I want to add a line on hover menu items just like what this site has on their navigation menu:
http://www.ovenbits.com

I tried to do this with css but the transition effect is ugly. How can I do this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Show what have you tried in a jsFiddle, then ask what is not working

Comment: Add `border-bottom` property on hover.

Comment: Do you like the way the line-on-hover works/looks in ovenbits.com?

Answer (score 4):

instead of using underline use border in bottom:

```
.menu a:hover { border-bottom:3px solid #fff;}
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/z2uu1dj4/

Answer (score 1):

```
Use code like this:

<ul>
    <li class="topnav-link">Home</li>
    <li class="topnav-link">About Us</li>
    <li class="topnav-link">Contact Us</li>
</ul>

ul{float:left; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.topnav-link {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0.8889em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 0.125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: border-bottom-color 50ms linear 0s;
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px;
}
.topnav-link:hover, .topnav-link.active {
    border-bottom-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, the live-on-over effect at ovenbits.com is realized by the following CSS rule:

```
.topnav-link {
    color: #F5F5F5;
    font-size: 0.8889em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding-bottom: 0.125em;
    transition: border-bottom-color 50ms linear 0s;
}
.topnav-link:hover, .topnav-link.active {
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<li class="topnav-link-item">
    <a href="/commerce" class="topnav-link">Commerce</a>
</li>
```

so the bottom border is placed on the `a` element (link).

The transition is applied to the border color property.